# Rails 4 ActionMailer subdomain urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

When a rails 4 application is hosted on a subdomain e.g. `sub.domain.com`, how can you get urls in Action Mailer templates to link to the subdomain correctly?

config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'sub.domain.com' }
```

action mailer template link example:

```
<%= user_url(@user) %>
```

In the email, the link shows as `www.domain.com/users/1` rather then `sub.domain.com/users/1`

Answer (score 6):

It’s actually easy. The best suggestion I have for solving this problem is that you create a before_filter that sets it on each request in ApplicationController.rb like so:

```
before_filter :set_mailer_host

  def set_mailer_host
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
  end
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work for action mailer, the links generated still link to `www.domain.com` not `sub.domain.com`

Comment: Works for me on Rails 4.1

Comment: You can also do the same by adding `gem 'action_mailer_auto_url_options'` to your Gemfile, especially if you are a Sidekiq user

Comment: Is this answer threadsafe in Rails 4.2? I'm leaning toward 'no' but I haven't seen definitive proof either way

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is still an issue for you, but I thought I'd add something helpful I found related to this.

Aside from adding your default_url_options in the various config files (be sure that you add that in all environments you need it), you will want to get the whole url, not just the path.

```
<%= url_for() %>
```

You can specify a subdomain or domain as a parameter, as well as several other options (from apidock):

> **url_for(options = nil)** public Generate a url based on the options
>   provided, default_url_options and the routes defined in routes.rb. The
>   following options are supported:
>
> :only_path - If true, the relative url is returned. Defaults to false.
>
> :protocol - The protocol to connect to. Defaults to ‘http’.
>
> :host - Specifies the host the link should be targeted at. If
>   :only_path is false, this option must be provided either explicitly,
>   or via default_url_options.
>
> :subdomain - Specifies the subdomain of the link, using the tld_length
>   to split the subdomain from the host. If false, removes all subdomains
>   from the host part of the link.
>
> :domain - Specifies the domain of the link, using the tld_length to
>   split the domain from the host.
>
> :tld_length - Number of labels the TLD id composed of, only used if
>   :subdomain or :domain are supplied. Defaults to
>   ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length, which in turn defaults to 1.
>
> :port - Optionally specify the port to connect to.
>
> :anchor - An anchor name to be appended to the path.
>
> :trailing_slash - If true, adds a trailing slash, as in
>   “/archive/2009/”
>
> :script_name - Specifies application path relative to domain root. If
>   provided, prepends application path.
>
> Any other key (:controller, :action, etc.) given to url_for is
>   forwarded to the Routes module.

I wound up using link_to with the "_url" end to the route.  Like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Yes', response_approvals_url(t: @secret_token) %>
```

Comment: script_name is what I was looking for.  Here's a DRY solution to making sure your cookies and ActionMailer both respect the full path of your application:  `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:script_name] = Rails.application.config.session_options[:path]` (in config/initializers/session_store.rb of a Rails 4 app)

Answer (score 1):

For more detailed information click here http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 and here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Send-emails-from-subdomains

```
 module UrlHelper
      def with_subdomain(subdomain)
        subdomain = (subdomain || "")
        subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
        [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join
      end

      def url_for(options = nil)
        if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
          options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
        end
        super
      end
    end

    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      include UrlHelper
    end
```

Add the following code to the file app/helpers/url_helper.rb

```
def set_mailer_url_options
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = with_subdomain(request.subdomain)
end
```

and modify the file app/controllers/application_controller.rb to add:

```
before_filter :set_mailer_url_options
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it, a caching issue. I use delayed_job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job to run the mailer. Turns out that when the delayed job script is running it seems to cache the mailer templates.

Solution: `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart`

That's it! Pays to know what is being cached and where.